# Use deserialize function on a `String`

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde

Given this function:

```rust
fn deserialize_factor_index<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<usize, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let buf: &str = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    let result = buf
        .split("_")
        .last()
        .map(str::parse::<usize>)
        .unwrap()
        .map_err(serde::de::Error::custom);
    result
}
```

I would like to know how I can apply it to a type `String`.
Like so

```rust
let key: String = "COL_0001";
let index: usize = ???
```

I thought I could do it if I had this, but then I don't know how to use this with `key`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct FancyIndex(#[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_factor_index")] usize);
```

Comment: If you want to implement fallible conversion from a string, it sounds like you actually want to implement [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html). You don't need to drag in all of serde for this.

Comment: Here's an example using `FromStr`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c6120fc9aaf2d29b9511cfc23ddc71d3

Comment: I'm not too familiar with using `serde` raw, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't actually parse the data into a structure, that is typically handled by secondary crates like `serde_json` or `serde_toml`. You will probably need to write a parser as part of the `Deserializer` trait, and that will be a lot of work. I agree with using `FromStr` instead is probably the way to go.